# error in kestrel asp.netcode

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I install visual studio 2015 update and dot net core 1 in my station (windows 10).
But when i start visual studio and create default asp.net core site and run it without changing a bit , i get following error :

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[17]
>         Connection id "0HKT2L6GCL845" bad request data: "The input string contains non-ASCII or null characters."
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.BadHttpRequestException: The input string contains non-ASCII or null characters.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Infrastructure.MemoryPoolIteratorExtensions.GetAsciiString(MemoryPoolIterator start, MemoryPoolIterator end)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.TakeMessageHeaders(SocketInput input, FrameRequestHeaders requestHeaders)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
>   warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>         Connection processing ended abnormally
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.BadHttpRequestException: The input string contains non-ASCII or null characters.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Infrastructure.MemoryPoolIteratorExtensions.GetAsciiString(MemoryPoolIterator start, MemoryPoolIterator end)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.TakeMessageHeaders(SocketInput input, FrameRequestHeaders requestHeaders)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()

but in other station every thing is ok . 
thanks

Comment: Assert if you have installed them in the correct order. First Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and then .NET Core for VS Preview 2. http://dot.net

Comment: What request do you send? This basically means that your url has non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @LexLi I do as you said . also i uninstall everything and install them again but error exists

Comment: @Pawel I just hit F5 to see the output . I mean the request is a get simple request . In older version of asp.net (MVC 5 ) every things is ok

Comment: @Amir - still there is a request sent to the app which is causing the issue. Without seeing the request (be it a default request) it is hard to tell where the issue is. It maybe a bug in tooling which sends an incorrect request or Kestrel itself but again - without a request (or a repro) can't tell what's going on. MVC5/ASP.NET 4.x is not relevant here - it is a different product that works differently, has separate tooling and is not using Kestrel.

Comment: @Pawel how can i find out what happed ? In my PC that simple project thrown error but in my laptop it is ok . There is no difference i think . Maybe a config or something else cause the error .

Comment: I think i finally find out . Problem is when i ran old MVC5 app in my local host and add some cookies , these cookies send to my asp.net core app too . when i clear my cookies , problem gone